# Can not reach endpoint served by Flask app deployed on OpenShift from my local machine

Tags: flask, python-requests, openshift

I have a very simple Flask app which serves a machine learning model that outputs a prediction given some text as input (classification task). The docker image of the app is successfully built and deployed in OpenShift.

I can contact the endpoint using `curl` from the terminal console inside OpenShift and get the expected response.

My goal is to be able to do the same from my local machine (outside OpenShift). In order to do so, I am trying to use the `requests` Python library, but I have not succeeded until now.

I have tried by following the [official OpenShift documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/rest_api/index.html#rest-api-example-python), to use the following script.

```py
import requests
import json

url = 'http://insert_ip_here:insert_port_here'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer insert_token_here'}

insert_text = "whatever_text_here"

data = json.dumps({'email-text':insert_text})

pred = requests.post(url, data, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

but I get the following error

```py
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='***', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /api (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000219721E9E48>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))
```

Please note that if I dockerize the app on my local machine and use the same script above (without the `headers` and `verify` parameters in `requests.post` and the url being http://localhost:8080) everything works fine.

**Updated**: Here is the app.py script

```py
import pickle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, request, abort, jsonify

# here is where I load the machine learning model 
with open('fasttext_classifier.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)

# create the application object as an instance of class Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

# add a decorator to the function “make_predict” defined below. The function just returns the prediction as JSON 
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def make_predict():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    predict_request = [data['email-text']]
    predict_request = np.array(predict_request)
    prediction = model.predict(pd.DataFrame(predict_request))
    output = [prediction[0]]
    return jsonify(predicted_class=output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Any idea what might be the cause of the error above?

Comment: can you share the snippet related on the flask app? are you sure you made it accessible from the outside?

Comment: I have updated the question as per @pep 1 comment. Not sure actually what should I do to make it accessible from outside.

Comment: it might be obvious but if you are using port 8080 because you have another app listening on port 80, did you updated your server's firewall and are you forwarding traffic accordingly?

Comment: Did you create a route to the service/pod?